# list of general purpose smd transistors, diodes and mosfets

Tags: transistors, surface-mount

I want to start with building up a little stock of smd components.

But i'm not sure where to start. Is there a list of general purpose smd Transistors, Diodes and (mos)fets?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check out Seeedstudio's Open Parts Library:

http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Open_parts_library

Comment: thnx this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Transistors:

2N3904
2N4906
BC546
BC547
BC548
MSPA44
MSPA92
MSPA46
2N2222

Diodes:

1N4007
1N4148
BA159

These are available from multiple distributors, i list the brand-names, you can also search just for the number eg. 3904 or 2222,

Comment: thnx! but if I see it correctly not all of them are smd

or do they all have a smd package also?

Comment: Yes sorry, a few of them are non SMD